# Tkinter master attribute and its possible use

Tags: python, tkinter

sorry for the long post but the topic deserves a full explanation.

Studying the master attribute of Tkinter I came up with the idea to use it
to pass, among the various Toplevel, a whole series of methods and properties grouped
in one of my class that I called "Engine" useful to any part of the application.

So the basic idea is to create a class to manage from outside the Tkinter application
the various widgets but also, operations made on a database.

The problem is how to call the various methods, proerties, of my class from all application
point, initializing this my class on application "**init**".

Basically how to keep the reference to this during all mainloop of the application.

So I thought of associating my class with the **master** attribute made available
from Tkinter and visible to the entire application with a simple **self.master** that in my case, to access to my class methods becomes **self.master.engine**.

So for example to invoke the on_read function located in the DBMS class which is inherited
from the Engine class, we can simply do

```
self.master.engine.on_read()
```

However, this is the meaning of the functions linked to the various buttons of
the simple app code showed below, the "Engine" class is initializing with

```
self.engine = Engine()
```

call on inint of

```
App(tk.TK)
```

Connection returns the connection to the database that is reads self.master.engine.con

and returns sqlite3.Connection object at 0x7f97668e11f0>

Engine shows the methods of the class Engine

- class: Engine
- get_button
- get_frame
- get_label
- on_connect
- on_read
- set_data

Child opens a Toplevel

Sqlite reads the data in the table people created in the class DBMS

That said, how does that sound?

Is it dangerous to use master’s to take your "toolbox" with you?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3 as lite


class DBMS:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.on_connect()
        self.set_data()
        
    def __str__(self):
        return "class: %s" % (self.__class__.__name__, )

    def on_connect(self,):
        self.con = lite.connect(':memory:')

    def set_data(self):

        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE people (name_last, age)")

        who = "Yeltsin"
        age = 72
        cur.execute("insert into people values (?, ?)", (who, age))

        who = "Guido"
        age = 64
        cur.execute("insert into people values (?, ?)", (who, age))
        cur.close()

    def on_read(self):
        
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM people"
        cur.execute(sql)
        rs = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return rs
        

class Engine(DBMS,):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def __str__(self):
        return "class: %s" % (self.__class__.__name__, )
    def get_frame(self, parent, padding=None):
        return ttk.Frame(parent, padding=padding)
    def get_button(self, parent, text, underline=0, ):
        return ttk.Button(parent, text=text, underline=underline,)
    def get_label(self, parent, text=None, padding=None):
        print(parent)
        return ttk.Label(parent, text=text, padding=padding,relief=tk.RIDGE,)
    
class Child(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent,):
        super().__init__(name="child")

        self.parent = parent
        self.init_ui()
        
    def init_ui(self):

        msg = ("I'm the {0} frame of {1}".format(self.winfo_name().capitalize(),
                                                 self.master.title()))

        self.title(msg)

        w = self.master.engine.get_frame(self, 8)

        btn = self.master.engine.get_button(w, "Sqlite")
        btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_read)
        btn.pack()

        btn = self.master.engine.get_button(w, "Close")
        btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_cancel)
        btn.pack()

        w.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)

    def on_read(self, evt=None):

        print(self.master.engine.on_read())
        
    def on_cancel(self, evt=None):
        self.destroy()
    
            
class Main(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent,):
        super().__init__(name="main")

        #parent.get_class_dir(self.master)
        #parent.get_class_dir(self.master.engine)
        self.parent = parent
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        w = self.master.engine.get_frame(self, 8)
        
        btn = self.master.engine.get_button(w, "Connection")
        btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_get_con)
        btn.pack()

        btn = self.master.engine.get_button(w, "Engine")
        btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_get_engine_attributes)
        btn.pack()

        btn = self.master.engine.get_button(w, "Child")
        btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_open_child)
        btn.pack()

        btn = self.master.engine.get_button(w, "Close")
        btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.master.on_exit)
        btn.pack()
        
        w.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)

    def on_get_con(self, evt=None):

        print(self.master.engine.con)

        msg = self.master.engine.con

    def on_get_engine_attributes(self, evt=None):

        print(self.master.engine)

        attributes = [x for x in dir(self.master.engine) if not x.startswith('__')]

        for attribute in attributes:
            print(attribute)

    def on_open_child(self, evt=None):
        Child(self,)
                
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_exit)
        self.title("Simple App")

        #here we add Engine class to master...
        self.engine = Engine()

        Main(self,)

        #self.get_class_dir(self)
        #self.get_class_dir(self.master)

    def get_class_dir(self, obj):

        attributes = [x for x in dir(obj) if not x.startswith('_')]

        for attribute in attributes:

            if attribute == "engine":
                print("attribute {0}  type {1}".format(attribute, type(attribute)))
               
                    
            elif attribute == "master":
                print("attribute {0}  type {1}".format(attribute, type(attribute)))

                    
    def on_exit(self, evt=None):
        if messagebox.askokcancel(self.title(), "Do you want to quit?", parent=self):
            self.destroy()               
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `self.master` may not refer to the root window (instance of `Tk()`) if `self` is not a child of `root` window.  For example, a frame inside another frame.  Better use `Widget.nametowidget()` function: `self.nametowidget(".")` will return the root window as long as `self` is any widget type of tkinter.

Comment: @acw1668 you are suggesting that I use the following construct: 
self.nametowidget(".").engine = Engine() ?

Comment: No, just use it to access `engine` elsewhere.

Comment: .@acw1668..sorry I’m confused, I don’t get it, How can keep a reference to my Engine class all around the app?. Do you have any plans, reference to read?

Comment: You have already created an instance of `Engine` inside instance of `App()`.  I just suggest you to use `self.nametowidget(".").engine` instead of `self.master.engine`.

Comment: @acw1668...ops..thank a lot...;)